# Setting a due date using business days

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to set a due date using business days based on date received plus a given number of days depending on what a particular test may be but am unsure how to use the while loop within an if/else if/else.  All attempts have resulted in Crystal showing an error that everything after the initial if is not part of the formula.  Main structure of the code comes from https://kenhamady.com/formulas/form17.shtml.

```
WhileReadingRecords;
DateVar Array Holidays;
DateVar Target:=Date({DATE_RECEIVED}); 
NumberVar Add; 
NumberVar Added := 0;

if {METADATA_REPOSITORY.FIELD_VARCHAR_16} = "Test_1" then

    NumberVar Add = 28;
    WHILE Added < Add
    Do (target := target +1;
        if dayofweek (target) in 2 to 6 and not (target in holidays)
            then Added:=Added+1
            else Added:=Added);
        Target

else if {ORDTASK.TESTGROUPNAME} = "Test_2" then

    NumberVar Add =14;
    WHILE Added < Add
    Do (target := target +1;
        if dayofweek (target) in 2 to 6 and not (target in holidays)
            then Added:=Added+1
            else Added:=Added);
        Target

//else 

    NumberVar Add = DateAdd("d", Tonumber({TESTS.DURATION}), {CENTRALRECEIVING.DATE_RECEIVED});
    WHILE Added < Add
    Do (target := target +1;
        if dayofweek (target) in 2 to 6 and not (target in holidays)
            then Added:=Added+1
            else Added:=Added);
        Target
```

Comment: you have mixed many things, what is the result you wish to see as formula output

Comment: Hi, @Siva.  The ideal final output would be a date that takes into account whether something is 'Test_1', 'Test_2', or neither and adds the proper amount of days to come up with a due date that takes business days and holidays into account.  All works well if the number of days added is the same for everything  but not so much with my cobbled together attempt to account for varying amounts of time to add.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: IS this a basic syntax or crystal syntax?

Comment: This is crystal syntax.

Comment: if this is a crystal syntax then formula shouldn't compile at first step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WhileReadingRecords;
DateVar Array Holidays;
DateVar Target:=Date({DATE_RECEIVED}); 
NumberVar Add; 
NumberVar Added := 0;

if {METADATA_REPOSITORY.FIELD_VARCHAR_16} = "Test_1" then

    NumberVar Add := 28;
    WHILE Added < Add
    Do (target := target +1;
        if dayofweek (target) in 2 to 6 and not (target in holidays)
            then Added:=Added+1
            else Added:=Added);
        Target;

//else 
if {ORDTASK.TESTGROUPNAME} = "Test_2" then

    NumberVar Add :=14;
    WHILE Added < Add
    Do (target := target +1;
        if dayofweek (target) in 2 to 6 and not (target in holidays)
            then Added:=Added+1
            else Added:=Added);
        Target;

//else 

    NumberVar Add := DateAdd("d", Tonumber({TESTS.DURATION}), {CENTRALRECEIVING.DATE_RECEIVED});
    WHILE Added < Add
    Do (target := target +1;
        if dayofweek (target) in 2 to 6 and not (target in holidays)
            then Added:=Added+1
            else Added:=Added);
        Target
```

Comment: Seems to have done the trick with just a slight modification for the last statement.  Used `NumberVar Add := ToNumber({TESTS.DURATION});` instead since the while adds the necessary days.  Thank you so much for the help with this!